# Why does the saveProject macro fail to execute in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, macro

I am trying to learn how to use macros in QGIS. As a first task, I would like to display a message whenever I save a project. That is to say, I would like to have this code executed:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
iface.messageBar().pushMessage("Info","PushMessageTest")
```

I tested this code in the Python Console, it works:
[image]

First, I macros them via *Settings* -> *Options...*, then change the *Enable macros* field to *Always (Not Recommended)*:
[image]

Then, I edit the `saveProject` function within *Project* -> *Properties...* -> *Macros* so that it contains the to be executed code. (I also make sure that the *Python Macros* tickbox above the function definitions is ticked.)
[image]

Yet, whenever I click on the save project icon (top left):
[image]
or press Command-S, the project is saved, but the message *PushMessageTest* does not show up.

I would like to know what I am doing wrong.

**Why does the saveProject macro fail to execute?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restarting QGIS solved the problem: I need to edit the macro, then the message does indeed show up upon saving a project.

Ideally, it would be better not having to do this, but this works.